# Is there a way to see the backlog ranking as of a certain date in JIRA?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

Our customers are implying that the development team is not adding stories into the sprint backlog from the backlog per their priority (ranking)?  Is there a way I can see how the stories were ranked in the backlog on a specific date before they were added to the sprint?

I am using v 5.2.11

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, no. But priority and ranking are different anyway. Priority is a grouping of issues into sets. Ranking is placing each issue in order. I would tell the customer that the dev team has to balance many other constraints when they add issues to a sprint